# Swift function not drawing circle in updated view

Tags: swift, uiview, drawing, viewcontroller, geometry

I have a stepper in my View Controller that updates variables(`redd1`,  `greenn1`, `bluee1`) in my `UIView`. `drawRect` draws an initial circle and `updateColor` is meant to draw a new circle on top of it with an updated color.  The variables get updated when I call `updateColor` and I know that they get passed through because when i have their values printed out in updateColor they are correct. `updateColor` won't draw a new circle.

```
class UIView1: UIView {

    var redd1 = 0.0;
    var greenn1 = 0.0;
    var bluee1 = 0.0;

    override init(frame: CGRect)
    {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
    {
        let circle2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: -25.0, y: 10.0, width: 100.0, height:100.0))
        circle2.layer.cornerRadius = 50.0
        let startingColor2 = UIColor(red: (CGFloat(redd1))/255, green: (CGFloat (greenn1))/255, blue: (CGFloat(bluee1))/255, alpha: 1.0)
        circle2.backgroundColor = startingColor2;
        addSubview(circle2);
    }

    func updateColor()
    {
        let circle = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: -25.0, y: 10.0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0))
        circle.layer.cornerRadius = 50.0;
        let startingColor = UIColor(red: (CGFloat(redd1))/255, green: (CGFloat(greenn1))/255, blue: (CGFloat(bluee1))/255, alpha: 1.0)
        circle.backgroundColor = startingColor;
        addSubview(circle);   
    }   
}
```

Comment: So circle2 is added to your view and circle is not added to your view?

Comment: yes and i know that its not behind it because i took circle 2 out to make sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not call `addSubview` in `drawRect`. Only use `drawRect` if you were going to draw a circle yourself (e.g. by calling `stroke` of a `UIBezierPath`). Or if you're going to add circles as subviews (as `CAShapeLayer` sublayers to the view's `layer`), the retire `drawRect` altogether.

But by calling `addSubview` in `updateColor`, you're not changing the color, but rather you're adding another subview every time. Likewise, by calling `addSubview` in `drawRect`, you're adding another subview there, too, every time the OS calls `drawRect`. For example, I ran your code, changing the color from black to red, to green, to blue, and triggered `drawRect` to be called again a few more times, and when I look at the view hierarchy in the view debugger, you can see all of the views in the view hierarchy:

[image]

This is a dangerous practice, because those subviews will add up over time, taking up memory.

If you're going to add subviews, I would suggest (a) `drawRect` is not the right place to be adding subviews; and (b) if you're determined to go the `addSubview` approach, decide whether you can remove the previous subviews before adding new ones.

Personally, if I wanted `drawRect` to draw circles of different colors, I would just `stroke` the `UIBezierPath`. For example:

```
class CircleView: UIView {

    var redd1: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    var greenn1 : CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    var bluee1: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let color = UIColor(red: redd1 / 255.0, green: greenn1 / 255.0, blue: bluee1 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        color.setStroke()

        let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 75, y: 75), radius: 50, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI * 2.0), clockwise: true)
        path.lineWidth = 2
        path.lineCapStyle = .Round

        path.stroke()
    }

}
```

By the way, you notice that we can retire `updateColor` entirely. With the above code, if you set either red, green, or blue, it will call `setNeedsDisplay`, which will trigger the view being redrawn automatically.

---

You report that the above isn't working. Well, I tried it with this code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var circleView: CircleView!
    @IBOutlet weak var redSlider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var greenSlider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var blueSlider: UISlider!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        redSlider.value = Float(circleView.redd1) / 255.0
        greenSlider.value = Float(circleView.greenn1) / 255.0
        blueSlider.value = Float(circleView.bluee1) / 255.0
    }

    @IBAction func valueChangedForSlider(sender: UISlider) {
        circleView.redd1 = 255.0 * CGFloat(redSlider.value)
        circleView.greenn1 = 255.0 * CGFloat(greenSlider.value)
        circleView.bluee1 = 255.0 * CGFloat(blueSlider.value)
    }
}
```

And it worked fine:

[image]

Comment: it stops drawing the first circle too when i don't use drawRect

Comment: If you're going to draw it yourself, use `drawRect` (see code snippet in my answer as an example). If you're going to use subview approach, (a) don't use `drawRect`; (b) do the initial setup in `awakeFromNIB` or something like that; and (c) when you update the color, remove the old subview and add a new one.

Comment: I used your code and it creates the circle, but now the function does not recognize when the values for red, green, and blue are changed by the steppers in my view controller.

Comment: i think the problem is that drawRect doesn't update or get called again each time the stepper is clicked

Comment: @Caleb - Then there must be doing else going on, because when I used `drawRect` rendition (with `didSet` observers on the red, green, and blue properties), it worked fine. See example in revised answer. Maybe the valueChanged action wasn't hooked up right or the `IBOutlet` for the circle view isn't set? Add a breakpoints or log statements and make sure you're getting to the relevant routines.

Comment: i tried to recreate your project in a separate file and for some reason got errors when i tried to run it

Comment: Well, I can't help you if you don't tell me what the errors are. Perhaps upload your project somewhere and I can take a look.

Comment: @Rob- could i email it to you

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that the both have the values which they should have.
The two circles which you are drawing are exactly on the same postion and both have exactly the same color according to your code snippet. How should they differ? Of course you can't see the two circles when they are having the same color and same position. They are overlayed.

Comment: circle is suppose to go on top of circle 2 with the new color created by the variables. and i know that it not just underneath because i took circle 2 out and it still doesn't show up